# My custom module routers and acl problem

Tags: module, adminhtml, magento-1, acl

I have a problem about my custom module. It is not shown in my admin panel menu and when I try to open it with its url, I see a 404 page.

My module config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Altar_Hashtag>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Altar_Hashtag>
  </modules>
  <global>
      <page>
          <layouts>
              <page>
                  <label>Share Contents</label>
                  <template>page/sharecontents.phtml</template>
              </page>
          </layouts>
      </page>
    <helpers>
      <hashtag>
        <class>Altar_Hashtag_Helper</class>
      </hashtag>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <hashtag>
        <class>Altar_Hashtag_Block</class>
      </hashtag>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <hashtag>
        <class>Altar_Hashtag_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>hashtag_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </hashtag>
      <hashtag_mysql4>
        <class>Altar_Hashtag_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
              <hashtag>
                <table>altar_hashtag_contents</table>
              </hashtag>
        </entities>
      </hashtag_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <hashtag_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Altar_Hashtag</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </hashtag_setup>
      <hashtag_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </hashtag_write>
      <hashtag_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </hashtag_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <hashtag>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Altar_Hashtag</module>
          <frontName>hashtag</frontName>
        </args>
      </hashtag>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
  <menu>
    <hashtag module="hashtag">
    <title>Hashtag</title>
    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    <children>
      <hashtag module="hashtag">
        <title>Manage Hashtag</title>
        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
        <action>hashtag/adminhtml_hashtag</action>
      </hashtag>
    </children>
    </hashtag>
  </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <hashtag translate="title" module="hashtag">
              <title>Hashtag</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <hashtag translate="title">
            <title>Manage Hashtag</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
          </hashtag>
              </children>
            </hashtag>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <hashtag>
          <file>hashtag.xml</file>
        </hashtag>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<acl>` and `<menu>` elements do not belong inside `<adminhtml>`, they have to be direct children of `<config>`.

Also although it works in `config.xml` for backward compatibility reasons, you should move these to a separate file `adminhtml.xml` to follow Magento conventions.

Comment: Thank you for help but still problem